# Where can I find the api supported by kernel32.dll?

Tags: windows, kernel32

Where can I find all the functions provided in kernel32.dll? I was able to find some functions [here](http://www.astercity.net/~azakrze3/html/win32_api_functios.html), but I don't know how authentic that site is. Is there an authentic site that lists out all the available functions with proper documentation. I searched online but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you specifically want to know about the functions in kernel32.dll? For legacy reasons that dll is still the entry point for a lot of windows api functionality, but the windows API is now far FAR larger than the 3 subsystems Windows 3.x offered (kernel, user and gdi).

The [System Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section in MSDN covers the APIs exported from kernel32.dll, and many more.

---

As MSDN no longer documents just the Kernel32 exports in a single list, you could use [DumpBin](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) to extract a list of all the exports... and then search for the function on MSDN.

Comment: It is because I am analyzing some old code that is using these functions.

Comment: Well, Microsoft no longer documents the kernel32 export list in a single document.

Answer (score 1):

I found this link -

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/9/2E911956-F90F-4BFB-8231-E292A7B6F287/GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso

It's the official Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Link now broken.

Answer (score 0):

The functions available in kernel32 change per version of Windows. New functions are added and some are taken away every release.

If you want a canonical list on your machine, fire up Depends.exe (ships with the Windows SDK) and load kernel32.dll into it. All of the kernel APIs are implemented as exports on Kernel32.

Given a function name, visit the MSDN documentation at msdn.microsoft.com. This is the official site that documents all of Microsoft's official Windows APIs.